# How to plot multiple PDFs with single function?

Tags: plotting, functions, matrix

I am trying to plot multiple PDFs with a single function using a matrix of values. Currently, I do it like this:

`g1 = Plot[PDF[WeibullDistribution[3, 11], x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Orange}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0.2}}];`

`g2 = Plot[PDF[WeibullDistribution[2.5, 10], x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0.2}}];`

`g3 = Plot[PDF[WeibullDistribution[2, 9], x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0.2}}];`

`Show[{g1, g2, g3}]`

However, I would like to create a matrix with the parameters of the PDF, i.e.,
`mat = {{3, 2.5, 2}, {11, 10, 9}}` and call a function that will plot all curves at once. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mat = {{3, 2.5, 2}, {11, 10, 9}};
colors = {Orange, Red, Blue};
Plot[Evaluate[
  Map[PDF[WeibullDistribution[#[[1]], #[[2]]], x] &, 
   Transpose[mat]]], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0.2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> colors]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Domen!